Lua Wireshark dissector: decoding an Ethernet frame within a UDP-based custom tunneling protocol
I'm trying to create a simple lua dissector for a custom UDP-based tunneling protocol containing two fixed-length fields followed by the tunneled Ethernet frame. I have the following script with help from ChatGPT (being a novice), however the Ethernet frame isn't decoded properly, and displayed as a binary blob (see screenshot). Help would be much appreciated.
Wireshark decoding
-- Define the protocol
my_proto = Proto("my_proto", "Custom UDP Tunneling Protocol")

-- Define the fields for the protocol
local f_id = ProtoField.string("my_proto.id", "ID", base.ASCII)
local f_timestamp = ProtoField.uint64("my_proto.timestamp", "Timestamp", base.DEC)
local f_tunneled_eth = ProtoField.bytes("my_proto.tunneled_eth", "Tunneled Ethernet Frame")

-- Assign fields to the protocol
my_proto.fields = { f_id, f_timestamp, f_tunneled_eth }

-- Dissector function
function my_proto.dissector(buffer, pinfo, tree)
    -- Set the protocol column to "Custom Proto"
    pinfo.cols.protocol = "MY_PROTO"

    -- Check if the packet is large enough for minimum fields
    if buffer:len() < 32 then
        return -- Not enough data for ID + Timestamp
    end

    -- Add protocol to the dissection tree
    local subtree = tree:add(my_proto, buffer(), "Custom UDP Tunneling Protocol")

    -- Extract the ID field (24 bytes)
    subtree:add(f_id, buffer(0, 24))

    -- Extract the Timestamp field (8 bytes)
    subtree:add(f_timestamp, buffer(24, 8))

    -- Extract the Tunneled Ethernet frame (starting from byte 32)
    local eth_buffer = buffer(32):tvb()
    local eth_dissector = Dissector.get("eth") -- Get the Ethernet dissector

    if eth_dissector then
        -- Call the Ethernet dissector to parse the tunneled frame properly, adding it directly to the tree
        eth_dissector:call(eth_buffer, pinfo, tree)
    else
        -- Fallback if Ethernet dissector is unavailable
        subtree:add(f_tunneled_eth, buffer(32), "Ethernet Frame (unrecognized)")
    end
end

I have tried the included lua script, expecting the tunneled Ethernet frame to be decoded correctly. However, it is displayed as a binary blob.

I've found the issue. Using eth_withoutfcs rather than eth within Dissector.get() solved the issue.
